# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'window')

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I have a problem in my Angular 8 project, everything runs fine with ng it works, but when it runs ng build --prod the project compiles without errors and sends it to the server and then presents this error, what can be causing this?:

```
main-es2016.9481fe84ed9e8ee610e7.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'window')
at main-es2016.9481fe84ed9e8ee610e7.js:1
at main-es2016.9481fe84ed9e8ee610e7.js:1
at Object.<anonymous> (main-es2016.9481fe84ed9e8ee610e7.js:1)
at Object.uki+ (main-es2016.9481fe84ed9e8ee610e7.js:1)
at i (runtime-es2016.f781f2a4125c40732329.js:1)
at Module.zUnb (main-es2016.9481fe84ed9e8ee610e7.js:1)
at i (runtime-es2016.f781f2a4125c40732329.js:1)
at Object.0 (main-es2016.9481fe84ed9e8ee610e7.js:1)
at i (runtime-es2016.f781f2a4125c40732329.js:1)
at t (runtime-es2016.f781f2a4125c40732329.js:1)
```

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are doing, but I wanna say that, if your server isn't an HTTP  web server, the Angular project will not run. Javascript for Web has the window global object. Javascript for Server (Nodejs) doesn't have.

Comment: Hard to say. I'd suggest turning on source maps and source map support. You'll see the line of source code that breaks.

Comment: how do i do it dear Dima Parzhitsky?

Comment: @RicardoOliveira Can you give more details ?

Comment: everything was working normally, I didn't make any changes to package.json, I tried to upload some changes just now to the server, and show me this.

Comment: @RicardoOliveira any library which is not compatible with angular version 8 ? If posible why dont you update angular ?

Comment: what type of changes did you done ?

Comment: Simple thing, html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how, but I deleted the `node_module` folder and the `package-lock.json` file and ran npm install and everything started working again. Thank you all.

Comment: Solved the problem miraculously. Thanks.